# How to be sure to enter the userDidEarnRewardHandler of the AdMob ad submission function?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, admob

In my iOS application I would like to write something to the database when someone has finished watching an ad. Here is the code:

```
if let ad = Ad.shared.rewardedAd {
            ad.present(fromRootViewController: self,userDidEarnRewardHandler: {
                // We write something in database
                self.dbRef.child("Users").child.("Coins").setValue(ServerValue.increment(1))
            })
        }
```

I know that if the user leaves the ad before it is finished then the completion block is not called. Only most of the time, when I test my application and wait until the ad is finished, this completion block is still not called. I would like to know how to solve this problem.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You should add flags corresponding to when the ad was closed in this method provided by `GADFullScreenContentDelegate`

`func adDidDismissFullScreenContent(_ ad: GADFullScreenPresentingAd)`